# How to disable sitemap.xml with robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, sitemap.xml

I have a custom robots.txt for my site.
I interest to disallow sitemap.xml, so my question: Is it enough to write:

```
Disallow: /sitemap.xml ?
```

Comment: Why would you want to disallow it? Is not of the very nature that search engines find your structure quicker? Yes, it would work unless you have allowed access implicitly.

Comment: Thank you, i don't want that the robots will crawl
my site and getting my site's structure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /sitemap.xml
```

allows all bots to crawl everything on your host except URLs whose paths start with `/sitemap.xml`. So these URLs, for example, should not get crawled:

- `http://example.com/sitemap.xml`
- `http://example.com/sitemap.xml.tar.gz`
- `http://example.com/sitemap.xml/`
- `http://example.com/sitemap.xml/foo`

So if your sitemap is at `http://example.com/sitemap.xml`, conforming bots won’t crawl it.

Comment: Why is this answer rated 0?! it seems legit